# Can't boot to Ubuntu from GT60 2OC

Tags: boot, msi

I have a Windows 8 laptop which boots Windows 7 fine. I updated it to the most recent BIOS from the MSI website. I had a GT60 ONC (msi-16f3). It would easily boot to a live CD and to Ubuntu and android-x86 alongside Windows.

I recently upgraded to a GT60 2OC (msi-16f4) and now I can't boot to the Ubuntu live CD. It shows the first screen then shows a flashing cursor in the upper left of the screen then just sits there. I used another PC to do a boot repair on my SSD containing my Windows with Ubuntu and Android. That worked to do the boot repair and I could use everything normally, but with the SSD back in my laptop it shows the purpleish screen and then does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the purple-ish frozen screen, try to hit `Ctrl+Alt+F7` or `Ctrl+Alt+F8` to see if you can access a standard terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing. It seems i was actually able to boot into recovery mode. Seeing this i altered the bootup code by basically just removing what was there and now it seems to sorta work... so far i have experienced some random crash that leaves it there with the caps lock light flashing.